# How can I get the values in the Matrix on my SSRS report to repeat?

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, repeat, bids

I know there must be a simple answer to this, but I can't find it.

I have added a couple of textboxes to a Matrix in a BIDS/SSRS report. I've given these textboxes values such as:

```
=Fields!WEEK1USAGE.Value
```

It works (after a fashion); when I run the report (either on the Preview tab, or on the Report Server site) I see the first corresponding data value on the report - but only one.

I would think that once a value has been assigned via expressions such as "*=Fields!WEEK1USAGE.Value*", each value would display (rows would automatically be added).

There must be some property on the Matrix or the textbox that specified this, but I can't see what it might be.

Here is how my report looks (very minimalistic, so far) in the Layout pane:

[image]

...and after running, on the Preview tab:

[image]

Obviously, I want the report to display as many rows as necessary, not just one. The textboxes do have a "RepeatWith" property, but there description doesn't sound interesting/useful/promising.

I don't see any property on the Matrix control that looks right, either.

I thought maybe the designer was only showing one row of values, and ran the report on the server, too, but there also it just shows the two values.

So what do I need to do to get *all* the data for a provided field?

Comment: Did you delete the Details group in Row Groups?

Comment: Not on purpose; I wouldn't know how to, so if I did it was an accident.

Comment: It is a obvious suggestion but check the dataset query to see if more than one row is being returned with the parameter values you are passing (if any). Also an image of your whole matrix in design mode could be useful.

Comment: Yes, I get all the data back in the Data tab when I run it (hundreds of rows).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrices are for display of grouped data and summary information, usually in a horizontally expanding pivot table type of format. Is a matrix really what you are after? Looking at your expression you have `=Fields!Week1Usage.Value` but in a matrix what I expect to see would be at least `=Sum(Fields!Week1Usage.Value)` or even better just `=Sum(Fields!Usage.Value)`. Then you would have ProactDescription as your row group and the week as your column group and it would all just work out everything for you, grouping and summing by Proact vertically and expanding the weeks out horizontally.

What seems to be happening is that you have no grouping on rows or columns and no aggregation so it is falling back to the default display which is effectively the `First` function - it displays the first row of data and as far as the matrix is concerned it has done its job because there is no grouping.

Without knowing your problem or data, I'll make up a scenario that might be what you are doing and discuss how the matrix does the heavy lifting to solve that problem. Let's say you have usage data for multiple Proacts. Each time one is used you record the usage amount and the date and time it is used. It could be used multiple times per day but certainly multiple times in a week. So you might be able to get the times each Proact is used from a table like so:

```
SELECT ProactDescription, TimeUsed, Usage
FROM ProactUsage
ORDER BY ProactDescription, TimeUsed
```

In your report you want to show the total weekly usage for each Proact over multiple weeks. Something like this:

```
Proact               Week1    Week2    Week3   ...
Description          Usage    Usage    Usage   ...
--------------------------------------------
Anise, Fennel 1 CT   20.00    22.50    16.35   ...
St John's Wort       15.20    33.90    28.25   ...
...
```

and so on. Using a dataset based on the SQL above we create a matrix and in the row group properties we group on `=Fields!ProactDescription.Value` and in the column group properties we group on a week expression like `=DateDiff(DateInterval.Week, Fields!TimeUsed.Value, Today)` and then in the intersection of the row and column we put `=Sum(Fields!Usage.Value)`. To display the header of the column nicely put an expression like

```
="Week " & DateDiff(DateInterval.Week, Fields!TimeUsed.Value, Today)
```

The matrix automatically does all the summing by week and product and expands the weeks horizontally for as many as you are reporting. For bonus points you can also put totaling at the end of the columns and the rows to show the total use of that Proact for the period (row total) and total use of all Proacts in that week (column total).

Comment: Yes, I reckon the Matrix is not the right "animal" for me; I simply need a grid to house the result set from a Stored Procedure. I tried the Table control, too, but it seemed even less user-friendly. It doesn't have to be fancy - just the data returned from the SP. All the necessary summing has already been done in the SP. What it returns is exactly what I need to display on the report.

Comment: Yes, if you are displaying a straight result set rather than doing dynamic summing then you want a table.

Comment: If only the Table were designed by the Delphi cats instead of a band of geeky geniuses (not that the Delphi cats weren't geniuses, but they knew how to make things as easy as possible).

Comment: Ah, yes, the old Delphi days - that was a Golden Age for programmers.